# I'm trying to run Armadillo on Mac OS but i keep getting the same error

Tags: c++, macos, operator-keyword, mat, armadillo

I'm trying to fill a matrix with the data that i have on a text file.

This is my code

```
int main() {

ifstream in;


int n=150;
int m=5;


mat coordinates (n,m);
coordinate.zeros();

in.open("test.txt");

for (int i=0; i<n ; i++) {
    for (int j=0; i<m ; j++)

        in >> coordinates(i,j);

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with the comand

`g++ -I/usr/local/include coordinates.cpp -O2 -larmadillo -llapack -lblas`

Everything seems ok so far but when i try to run the program i get the following error

`error: Mat::operator(): index out of bounds
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: Mat::operator(): index out of bounds
Abort trap: 6`

I tried everything i could think of but nothing worked. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code: the second loop has `i<m` instead of `j<m`.

Also, don't directly use the `>>` operator with matrices, because you cannot check for whether an element was actually read. Instead, you can simply load the entire file using the `.load()` member function.

It's a good idea to thoroughly read the [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) before posting basic questions.

```
// simple way

mat coordinates;
coordinates.load("test.txt", raw_ascii);   // .load() will set the size
coordinates.print();
```

OR

```
// complicated way

ifstream in;
in.open("test.txt");

unsigned int n=150;
unsigned int m=5;

mat coordinates(n, m, fill::zeros);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<m; ++j)
        {
        double val;
        in >> val;

        if(in.good())  { coordinates(i,j) = val; }
        }
    }

coordinates.print();
```